# php cron job acting like browser with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, server, cron, request-uri

Is it possible to create a cron job that will act as a normal browser that will send a $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?

Because when I do /usr/bin/php -q __path_to my php file____

I get stuff like this

```
$_SERVER['SHELL'] 
$_SERVER['MAILTO']  
$_SERVER['USER'] 
$_SERVER['PATH'] 
$_SERVER['LANG'] 
$_SERVER['SHLVL'] 
$_SERVER['HOME'] 
$_SERVER['LOGNAME'] 
$_SERVER['_'] 
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']
```

But when I run from browser I get more stuff

```
$_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']
$_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX']
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
$_SERVER['GATEWAY_INTERFACE']
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
$_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION']
$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
$_SERVER['PATH']
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']
$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']
$_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
$_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID']
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']
```

I also tried **lynx** and **curl** but it doesn't seems to do it...

Thanks if someone have an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons I block wget in my script...

I finally found what I needed :

it's a chrome extension http://www.crontabs.org/ you can setup a page to open and reloads each x minutes, hours, etc...

Thanks for the other answers

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ajax for send call to server, using setTimeout Method you can set interval, on this you have to send call to server or your url for sending request.

But its not work after shutdown your PC, so do clear these all things before implement.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to run cron from url:

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/_path_to_your_php_file_
```